# Add release notes to Xcode project

Tags: xcode, release

Is it possible to add release notes / "What to test" notes to an Xcode project before archiving the project and submitting it to AppStoreConnect?

There is some documentation for Xcode Cloud, but none for manually archiving the app: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/including-notes-for-testers-with-a-beta-release-of-your-app

Is this possible?